# adding a cell to an existing table in c# asp Htmltablerow

Tags: c#, asp.net

is there anyway i can add a column/cell to a row that i am pulling from a different page on my website using

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow
```

Also, is there a way i can change the width of the row i am pulling?

Answer (score 0):

**Create a row and cell**

```
HtmlTableRow htmlRow = new HtmlTableRow();
HtmlTableCell htmlCell = new HtmlTableCell();
```

**Add a cell to a row**

```
htmlCell.InnerHtml  = "your data goes here";
htmlRow.Cells.Add(htmlCell);
```

**Add row in your table**

```
HtmlTable htmlTable = new HtmlTable();
htmlTable.Rows.Add(htmlRow);
```

You can add CSS style using this code

```
htmlCell.Attributes.Add("style", "width:50px;");
```